# Eloquent select field with relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

Here is the controller

```
$query = ( new Product() )->where( 'quantity', '>', 0 )
        ->where( 'product_category_id', '!=', null )
        ->where( 'soft_delete', 0 )
        ->whereBetween( 'price', [ $priceFrom, $priceTo ] )
        ->with( [
               'campaign' => function ( $q ) {
               $q->where( 'stock', '>', 0 );
               $q->where( 'expire', '>', Carbon::today()->toDateString() );
        }] )->first()// Check the campaign table if it has any record or not
            ->orderBy( 'price', $sort );
```

Now I am try to get the price from the campaign so what I trying to do in blade is this

```
@if(count($product->campaign))
   <del>$425.00</del>
   {!! $product->campaign->price !!}
@endif
```

but I got

> Property [price] does not exist on this collection instance.

how can I select the price from the campaign?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = Product::where('quantity', '>', 0)
        ->whereIsNotNull('product_category_id')
        ->where('soft_delete', 0)
        ->whereBetween('price', [$priceFrom, $priceTo])
        ->with([
            'campaign' => function ( $q ) {
                $q->where( 'stock', '>', 0 );
                $q->where( 'expire', '>', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
             }
         ])
         ->first()// Check the campaign table if it has any record or not
         ->orderBy('price', $sort);
```

Property [price] does not exist on this collection instance. This error because your Product model have HasMany campaign relation.
For get separate campaign price use

```
@if(count($product->campaign))
   <del>$425.00</del>
   @foreach ($product->campaign as $compaign)
   {!! $coampaign->price !!}
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: thanks I just got it, the problem was here `'campaign' => function ( $q ) {
                              $q->select(['id', 'product_id', 'price']);` has to put this ` $q->select(['id', 'product_id', 'price']);` and in the blade this worked fine `{!! $product->campaign[0]->price !!}` thanks a lot davit for tring to help me.

Comment: Your script you get only first campaign price.Maybe product does not have compaign. You must be check` @if(!empty($product->campaign[0])) 
      $product->campaign[0]
@endphp`